# C++ map set hybrid

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, set

I have folder information in

```
struct folder
{
    int id;
    int folder_count;
    long long size;
};
```

I need to keep folders (can be 1000 or more ) sorted by their folder_count and size respectively (folder having most `folder_count` must be first, and if there are same `folder_count`, it needs to be sorted by size).

I have achieved it by custom comparator

```
struct folder_comparator
{
    bool operator() (const folder& a, const folder& b) const 
    {
        return a.folder_count>b.folder_count || (a.folder_count==b.folder_count && a.size>=b.size);
    }  
};
```

and putting folders into set

```
set <folder, folder_comparator> folders;
```

But in the meantime folder gets many updates. I can achieve this by `map` with key being `id` of folder.

```
map<int, folder> folders;
```

But in this case i cannot keep custom order (mentioned above).

I need both. (keep custom order and `O(1)` or atleast `O(log(N))` complexity search)

What data structure or hybrid of set and map can help me in this situation?

Comment: `folder_comparator` doesn't meet the requirements of strict weak ordering, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior. Among other problems, it declares that `f` is less than `f`, for any `folder f`. Change `>=` to `>`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that,  Igor. But this comparator works (may be not perfect). anyways, main question is not that comparator.

Comment: @Elbek The comparator does not work. It breaks one rule of comparators which is that they must return false given two identical arguments. You only have to change `>=` to `>` to fix this, so do it.

Comment: When you say "folder gets many updates", do you mean that its `folder_count` and/or `size` may change? In this case, you can't store them in `set<folder>`. Or at least, whenever you need to change those, you'd need to remove the folder from the set, update it, and insert back.

Comment: undefined behaviour is never irrelevant to other parts of the code

Comment: I'd probably have `map<int, folder>` together with `set<int, my_comparator>` or `set<map<int, folder>::iterator, my_comparator>`. Where `my_comparator` would take two IDs or two iterators, look up corresponding folders in the map and compare them. Again, remember to remove and re-insert the ID/iterator into the set whenever you change any member of the folder that affects the order.

Comment: And I'm suggesting a data structure that combines a map and a set of iterators into that map. In what way does this fail to meet your requirements?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If i have `set<folder, folder_comparator>` to store folders sorted, and to have `map<int, set<folder, folder_comparator>::iterator  >' for faster access. And keep iterators updated whenever i change folder_count or size. It will have `O(log(N)+log(N)+1)` = `O(log(N))` complexity. It should work. Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for reminding about comparator. I get it now. Thanks @IgorTandetnik

Comment: That would probably work, too. Recall that you would need to remove and re-insert the folder in the set whenever you want update `folder_count` or `size` - at which point an original iterator to it would be invalidated and the new one obtained, so don't forget to update the map, too.

Comment: `boost::multiindex` would fit your need perfectly but it has learning curve.

Comment: The easiest way to write a valid *Comparer* is to use `std::tuple`'s `<` (or `>`). `std::tie(a.folder_count, a.size) > std::tie(b.folder_count, b.size);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need both. (keep custom order and O(1) or atleast O(log(N)) complexity search)

This means [Boost Multi-Index](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) most probably will fit your need perfectly with hashed index on id and non unique sorted index with your (fixed) comparator. It has learning curve though but it seems it would worse the effort in your case (rather than maintain 2 independed containers)

PS you current comparator does not meet requirement for strict weak ordering which is part of all sorted standard and boost containers. You need to fix it in either case. Easiest way to provide proper comparator is to use `std::tie`:

```
bool operator() (const folder& a, const folder& b) const 
{
    return std::tie( a.folder_count, a.size ) > std::tie( b.folder_count, b.size );
}
```